# gerund or infinitive after the verb "to go"

Tags: verbs, infinitive-vs-gerund

I know that when the activity is outdoors and done especially in your free time, we should use the ing ending after the verb to go, Example: I go swimming every morning....or they go running every sunday. But of the following examples, which one is correct and why?

> 1. I go playing football at weekends.
> 2. I go to play football at weekends.
> 3. We go to see a film every sunday
> 4. We go seeing a film every sunday

Why is it that 2 & 3 sounds right to me despite the fact that you have to go out to do the activities and in your free time?

Comment: **go seeing**  is not idiomatic and has never been idiomatic in English. They might go walking the dog, but they don't go seeing a movie.

Comment: In the US here, I would say "I might go walk the dog", but that's not "technically" correct English; I would write "I might go to walk to the dog." I don't think I'd say "I might go walking the dog"; however, I would say "I might go walking."

Comment: Perhaps "go"+gerund-participle works where the outdoor activity is intransitive, but not where it's transitive. "I go swimming/climbing/hiking/driving/walking/running every Sunday": all OK.  But most of the following sound slightly odd: "I go swimming lakes every Sunday",  "I go climbing mountains every Sunday":, "I go running a marathon every Sunday":,  "I go walking the dog", "I go driving the car every Sunday".  A bit more doubtful still: "Do you like going climbing mountains?"  But "Do you like going climbing?" is fine (as is "Do you like climbing mountains?").

Comment: I think the gerund is acting as a plain, old noun and it has to be an activity.  You can't make a noun transitive, but you can make a gerund transitive, so that could be the case. I would say "I go swimming in lakes every Sunday", but just "I go climbing every Sunday" or "I climb mountains every Sunday." I would not say "Do you like going climbing?" I would say "Do you like to go climbing?"

Comment: Yes, I think it has to be intransitive most of the time: I go sneaking around. I go partying around town, I go sledding in the mountains. I go skating (on a pond). But almost all of them are activities whose -ing form can stand on its own as a noun.

Comment: @Nicholas Castagnola: There's nothing wrong with "I might go walk the dog".   As you say, **go** + -ing form is not followed by a direct object,

Comment: I didn't say that there was anything wrong with "I might go walk the dog" although if I typed it, I would be less formal and either write "I might go to walk the dog" or "I might walk the dog". I said there may be something wrong with "I might go walking the dog."

Comment: I am just telling you how I would say it. I do not think it can be transitive: "I might go walking my dog"---no; "I might go walking with my dog in the woods"---yes. I don't know whether that's a steadfast rule. I said above that activities, especially sports, take the go + **V-ing**; however, other activities  do too: I go paryting (at the clubs) every weekend; I go shopping (at the store) once a week. But normally it's a sports activity and its intransitive: running, sprinting, sailing, walking, swimming, skiing, sledding (sledging).

Comment: Even something stupid like, "I like to go yelling down the street once a week" works. "I like to go screaming to my mother once in a while when I'm upset."

Answer (score 1):

I think the "outdoors and free time" guide is not reliable. English is, unfortunately, pretty inconsistent about when to use the gerund or the infinitive. For example both of these are fine:

> I want **to go to fish** on the lake this weekend
>   I want **to go fishing** on the lake this weekend

The gerund sounds a little more natural, as it can be awkward to repeat the same proposition more than once in a sentence, but the infinitive is fine.

Otherwise certain verbs seem to prefer one or the other, but I feel like you have to memorize these case by case:

> I **go to play** piano on weekends.
>
> I **go to sleep** by 10 every night.
>
> I **go surfing** when the weather is clear.
>
> I **go shopping** in the morning before school.

Answer (score 1):

Why this insistence on going?

I play football at weekends. (On weekends/on the weekend)

We see a film every Sunday.

What was gained by using "to go"? What is lost by discarding it?

Comment: I agree that "I play football at weekends" sounds much better than the slightly odd-sounding "I go to play football at weekends".  On the other hand, "We see a film every Sunday" is rather vague: it might mean that you watch one on television or on your computer.  "We go to see a film every Sunday", on the other hand, usually means the same thing as "We go to the cinema every Sunday".

Comment: Because Philip, my question  has to do precisely with the verb "to go". I don't really need information about "going". Example: "I go to see a film every sunday" which apparently is correct, even though is an specific activity for which we have to to go out to do and in our free time?  And why it is wrong to say: "I go seeing a film every sunday" How I am supposed to know which verbs go in their  infinitive form and which verbs to with the ending "ING" after del verbo go? (call it gerund or gerundive) Please, I still can't get it, the absence of a rule makes it more confusing.

Comment: You use them all of the time; that's how. I told you that the trick is that it is an activity and it can be a noun on its own without being a gerund.  Swimming is a noun; sailing, hiking, running, walking, partying---these are all activities that are mostly sports, but some activity nevertheless.  "I go sightseeing" is fine because "sightseeing" is a noun; it's an activity.

Comment: In the US, when speaking, we usually say "go +bare infinitive" such as "I go play football on the weekend" except we don't say it when it is in third person singular such as "he goes play football." That, we'd never say; never "goes play", but yes to "go play". It's not grammatically correct, but it's a shortened way to say it.  I would never write "go play" or "go do"; I'd always write "go to play" or go to do", but it's colloquial speech here.

Comment: What country are you in? What's your native language? Just wondering because I may be able to help. I know some French. I doubt it's French though.

Comment: Good point, Nicholas.  In the UK we say "I go and play football at the weekend".

Comment: We say that too: "go and play"; however, that's grammatically incorrect too. We just don't like the correct "go to play" in the UK or US, so, here in the US, we say "go do"; however, as I've stated, with third person singular, we would always say "goes to do". If you say it to mean in short, "I go to the park and I play football there", that's fine.  "Go upstairs and do your homework", we'd say "go do your homework" or the formal way "go to do your homework" or "Go upstairs to do your homework!"

Comment: The "to go and ..." construction is perfectly grammatical British English (whereas "go walk the dog" is not - it sounds American to my ear). There is possibly a slight difference in meaning. The infinitive probably implies purpose, whereas "go and" implies one connected activity.

Answer (score 0):

Nos. 2 and 3 are correct.  The rest are wrong; however, they should read as follows:

> "I go to play football **on** weekends." (Use "on" for "weekends; not
>   "at"; "on weekends".)
>
> "We go to see a film every **Sunday**." (capitalized "S" for "Sunday".)

You are confusing present participles and gerunds here.  "Swimming" is a common gerund that we use almost always as a noun because we don't like to say the word "natation", so swimming is one of those gerunds that have become straight-up nouns today.  Others, especially sports, are "jogging", "running", "biking". Examples:

> "Did you know that swimming, jogging, and running are all great
>   activities?"

Obviously, this rule isn't completely consistent and so you will just have to learn them.  I actually think your examples are rare cases of the "gerundive" in English, rather than the "gerund", i.e.

"The lake is worth **swimming** in."

("swimming" is a **gerundive**; not a gerund herein.)

***NOTE: I'm partially wrong in my explanation as to why we say "going swimming", but not completely.  Look at this link for more information:***

http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/7241044724

Comment: In BrE, "at weekends" is correct.

Comment: Okay, then rjpond says it's correct in BrE; I've never heard it in American and Canadian English...not once!

Comment: According to your explanation, it would be correct then to say: " I go playing football on weekends" If it is wrong, why would that be? Because it has a different meaning? Is there a rule to indicate when should use the infinitive or ing end? What about these two? A. I want to go to fish on the lake this weekend
B.  I want to go fishing on the lake this weekend

Comment: It's hard for me to explain. When talking about an activity such as sailing, hiking, biking, running, diving, etc--any activity, you can say "going + the gerund / noun".

Comment: "Playing" is not a specific activity; football is the activity, but it's not a "gerund".

Comment: I have added a link above for you to use to explain it better than I have.  Sorry I couldn't help more.